# how to set a map value in velocity

Tags: velocity

I tried to define a map in velocity template using the following syntax. It did not work, does anyone know how to declare a map of constant values in velocity?

```
#set ($mymap = {"key" : "value" , "key2" : "value"})
```

EDIT: I am using 1.6.3 version of velocity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It worked for me. Maybe you have very old version of Velocity?

```
#set ($mymap = {"key" : "value" , "key2" : "value2"})

get: ${mymap.key} 
or:  ${mymap.get("key")}
```

Comment: @Shamik So what is the problem exactly - it throws a syntax error? You can't get a value by a key?

Comment: I was wrong, I had a different version(1.4) of velocity in my class path and as a result, map was not working. Once I removed the unwanted jars from the pom, it started to work. Thank you for your help.